# frequency division by 5 using only JK flip flops

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

I've was asked to design a circuit using nothing but JK Flip Flops and a clock that will divide the clock's frequency by 5.
while obvious solutions can be done using other logical gates i can't seem to solve this one with nothing but Flip Flops.
any ideas?

Comment: Asked by whom? I somehow smell a homework question

Comment: Think about whether you could do this with a counter.  Can you use JK flip-flops to implement a counter?  Otherwise, we are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: the web has all your answers in life, the secret is learning how to learn , after which you forget 99% of what you have studied but learn higher levels of wisdom in anything, including electronics. THis is the purpose of education. Not just to teach fundamentals but for you to teach yourself how to learn faster

Comment: hint: google JK counter modulo 5

Comment: And are you being "asked" to provide a 50% duty cycle on the output? That is, a square wave output? That cannot be done without at least one extra logical element -  an exclusive OR gate.

Comment: I tried the synchronous binary sequence, that did not yield a solution. But the LFSR pattern of 0001100011... does yield a full synchronous solution. Connect FF0 to FF1 and FF1 to FF2 as shift registers. Now the only inputs to be manipulated are J and K of FF0. You have the 3 outputs (plus their inverted) from the 3 FFs as possible connections to the 2 inputs. There is a pair of connections that gives the desired sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is in "Gateless Scalers with J-K Flipflops", written in 1968 by P A Neeteson of Philips. This document shows seven configurations of 3 J-K flipflops which all divide by 5. The best is attached; this is synchronous and has an output which is negative-going on the 5th clock.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2wfpi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can preset the flip-flops, put five in a row.  Tie Q to the j of the next one and Q' to the k.  On the last one tie Q to the J of the first one and Q' to the k.  Same clock goes to all the flip-flops.  Preset the first Q to 1 and the next 4 to zero.  The 1 will just keep cycling through the 5 flip-flops giving you the divide by 5.

Comment: You only need 3 jk flip flops and a two input NAND gate. See http://www.electronicshub.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/modulo-%E2%80%93-5-counter.jpg

Comment: @Jim Dearden, the problem the problem states nothing but JK flip-flops allowed.

Comment: I know but its like asking "how do I solder while standing on one leg?"- Its not a realistic constraint and It wastes everyone's time. This question has all the hallmarks of unresearched homework which we try to avoid putting an answer on here - it just feeds the trolls.